# Несколько мелких вопросов по C#

Tags: c#

Добрый день. Решил не городить несколько тем, а написать все в одну.

1) Есть ли принципиальные различия между: `Task.Factory.StartNew` и `Task.Run`?

2) Не могли бы простым языком объяснить практическое применение ключевого слова `volatile`? На msdn есть пример, но смысл его плохо до меня доходит.

3) В последнем примере (для .NET 4.0) [исследования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/research/221526/%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-producer-consumer-pattern), проведенного @VladD, описывается метод:

```
void Consumer()
{
    foreach (var s in q.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processing: {0}", s);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Processed: {0}", s);
    }
}
```

Я использовал подобную реализацию для записи с разных потоков в один файл, примерно так:

```
private void ErrorWrite()
    {
        foreach (var item in Error_Collection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(Path_Error_File))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

Код работает стабильно, но вот данный код работает через раз, причем при увеличении числа потоков - практически совсем перестает работать:

```
private void ErrorWrite()
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(Path_Error_File))
        {
            foreach (var item in Error_Collection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                    sw.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
     Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

С чем подобное может быть связано?

Comment: Хм. По поводу 3-го примера — у вас есть несколько потоков, пишущих в `Path_Error_File`?

Comment: @VladD, все верно. Несколько потоков пишут в один текстовый файл.

Comment: @z668: Тогда, наверное, во втором варианте файл блокирован существованием `StreamWriter`'а? Хуже того, вы должны как-то синхронизировать доступ к файлу, т. к. одновременная запись из разных потоков ни к чему хорошему не приведёт. Почему бы вам не держать лишь один поток для сброса ошибок в файл?

Comment: @VladD, возможно, Вы меня не так поняли. Я использовал вашу статью с паттерном поставщик\потребитель. ErrorWrite() работает в отдельном потоке, запускаемом в конструкторе формы. Error_Collection - это BlockingCollection, данные в нее уже заносятся из разных потоков.

Comment: @z668: Хм. Странно, что два практически одинаковых вызова ведут себя по-разному. Проблемы, если и есть, должны быть одинаковыми.

Comment: @VladD, разобрался, в чем проблема. Оба варианта рабочие, просто один медленнее другого. Но не суть. Проблема в самой Win 8.1 x64 - она некорректно показывала размер файла (показывала 0 кб, хотя на самом деле данные там были).

Comment: @z668: А, понятно. Дело в том, что видимый размер файла обновляется операционной системой, когда _файл закрывается_. В первом случае у вас файл закрывался после каждой строки, а во втором — только после окончания записи.

Вот.

---
Вот [объяснение, почему так получилось](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/26/10251026.aspx), от Реймона Чена (это такой Microsoft'овский Чак Норрис).

Comment: @VladD,спасибо, теперь понятно, из-за чего такое происходит. С современными компьютерами могли бы сделать и динамическое отображение размера, авось не пентиум 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Особой разницы нет - Run - это "сокращенная" версия StartNew с null, переданным в качестве токена отмены таска
2. volatile нужен для того, чтобы сообщить CLR, что член, помеченный этим модификатором, может быть использоован одновременно из нескольких потоков. Зачем это нужно? Дело в том, что в силу некоторых хитрых колдунств, связанных с оптимизацией многопоточного кода, инструкции  в целях оптимизации могут, например, "поменяться местами". В случае однопоточного выполнения (то есть в подавляющем большинстве случаев) это не будет иметь никаких последствий. Однако же логика исполнения программы с учетом нескольких потоков становится гораздо сложнее, и подобные оптимизации уже не проходят бесследно, в результате чего ваш код будет работать не так, как ожидалось. Так вот volatile позволяет это предотвратить.

Comment: По первому пункту: разница есть, и она в некоторых случаях довольно велика, см. [здесь](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).